# Amazon EC2 FTP - fails on "SITE CHMOD 644" command

Tags: ftp, amazon-ec2

This is driving me crazy... gave up on SFTP to my EC2 instances, and now trying FTP.

I've got it setup, and it was working fine for a few minutes, but then it threw this error when trying to write a file, and has been doing the same thing ever since...

```
220 Microsoft FTP Service
FEAT
530 Please login with USER and PASS.
USER administrator
331 Password required for administrator.
PASS ********
230 User administrator logged in.
SITE CHMOD 644 /xxx.docx
500 'SITE CHMOD 644 /xxx.docx': command not understood
QUIT
221
```

EDIT: Actually i got that slightly wrong... it failed the first time it tried to write a file (from Springloops, log:)

```
Creating directories and files
Creating directory: App_Browsers/ [755]
Changing mode of App_Browsers to 755
Extracting file: App_Browsers/Form.browser...OK
Uploading file: App_Browsers/Form.browser [644]
R: 
interrupted
```

Any idea why this might have happened?

I'm about to throw the towel in with this stupid EC2... its really getting the better of me (and burning a whole lot of precious time!).  ugh!

Comment: Using FTP is an extremely vulnerable security risk.  I run an sshd server on Windows and use ssh to copy files/directories securely.  You may also run rsync over ssh, making it easier to update larges sets of files.

Comment: Yeah i'm aware of the security risks jeff, however i'm just trialling EC2 at the moment, and already wasted too much time trying to setup a sftp server (unsuccessfully).  I just want to get my dev code up there and start performance testing to see whether a small instance will cope with my websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not every FTP service support every ftp command.  If you really need the SITE command then install a different ftp server on your EC2 instance.  You can try ProFTPD.  [Installation instruction for ProFTPD](http://ajohnstone.com/achives/setting-up-an-ftp-server-with-proftpd-on-ec2-2/)

Comment: thanks for the link, that'll be quite useful i'm sure.  However i've abandoned EC2 for now, opting to stick with shared hosting as i think it suits my immediate needs better.  Still, appreciate the link.